# Using Hammer.js on WeChat minigame

Tags: touch, hammer.js, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I've tried to use Hammer.js for touch UX on WeChat minigame.
I searched for a while but could not find any similar question or answer.

First, I just tried to use Hammer.js in the normal way.
After creating Canvas using `document.createElement('canvas')` with help of `weapp-adapter.js`, initialized Hammer.js like this:

```js
        this._hammer = new Hammer(canvas);
        this._hammer.on('tap', (event: HammerInput) => {
            console.log('tap', event);
        });
```

But the console logs nothing on the touch event.
As Canvas of WeChat minigame has no event handlers, this is quite normal.

Then, how can I use Hammer.js on WeChat minigame?

Comment: If that is impossible or so hard, is there another gesture-parsing library like Hammer.js that can be used on WeChat mini-game?

Answer (score 0):

Hammer.js works well with WeChat mini-game.
My mistake was in `import` statement for Hammer.js.

Before posting this question, I used

```js
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs'
```

, which didn't work as I expected.
I modified this line as

```js
import 'hammerjs'
```

and it worked. All the touch UX events are logged on the console such as `tap`, 'pan`, etc.

But that kind of import is less intuitive. I mostly use the `import` statements as `import SOMETHING from 'somemodule'`.
Although I write this answer by myself, I'd love to be answered again if someone let me know in more detail.